# How do I get more Gems?

Tags: uncharted-golden-abyss

Gems are a sort of Bounty you can get in Uncharted for defeating enemies, but I didn't get all of them in my first play through. I *absolutely most* get all of the gems.

Do just random enemies drop Gems/bounties, or do I need to get them from specific enemies? What does "scarce" and "rare" mean for Gems, the chance they'll drop from enemies?

Answer (score 1):

The other way to complete your bounty sets, including Gems, is to use the black market and near app to trade items, it seems to be very difficult to obtain the rare and scarce items simply by continuing to kill enemies in game. There are no specific enemies who have specific bounties, the rare and scarce items are just less likely to be dropped after a kill.

Unfortunately the near app and black market are not very easy to use, I found some useful information [here](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/Uncharted/Uncharted-Golden-Abyss-Black-Market/td-p/15328529) on how to use the trade system.

The best way is to go to a forum and seek out players looking to actively trade bounties and friend them on PSN so you can trade with active players straight away as trades expire very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "scarce" and "rare" describe how likely it is to get the gems and yes, gems are dropped by random enemies. You can replay every chapter from the main menu after finishing it. As Colin mentioned, you could get the gems via near and the black market but you need enough friends playing the game.

You can farm them in chapters 28, 29 and 31-34. One spot for farming is found in chapter 28 after the cutscene with Dante. Take the dragon sniper and kill the four enemies. Load the last checkpoint and repeat.